# CSS Media Queries Different from the actual phone

Tags: css

I have a problem in my css media queries. i have 2 version of my websites. a mobile and a desktop. I used a application to test my design in both mobile and desktop. when i test my design. it looks good but when i actually test it in a mobile phone, it has a problem especially in the margin. what seems to be the problem?

the position of the icon, the design of the website is different from the application i used.

example: i used a application that can test 480x800 mobile resolution and it works fine but when i used my lenovo a690 with a resolution of 480x800. the design looks different. even the sizes and zoom. my phone views the website so small even though it views larger in the applicaiton i used to test designs of different resolutions. can someone help me. thx!

here is my media query

```
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "../../css/global/reset.css"/>
    <!-- 480x800 Phones -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "only screen and (max-width : 800px) and (max-height : 480px)" href = "../../css/professor/main_mobile481799_landscape.css"/>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "only screen and (max-width : 480px) and (max-height : 800px)" href = "../../css/professor/main_mobile481799_portrait.css"/>
    <!-- 320x480 Phones -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "only screen and (max-width : 480px) and (max-height : 320px)" href = "../../css/professor/main_mobile_landscape.css"/>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" media = "only screen and (max-width : 320px) and (max-height : 480px)" href = "../../css/professor/main_mobile_portrait.css"/>
```

Comment: have a link for your site ?

Comment: this is the mobile version of the site. when i test it in a desktop using application that views as 480x800 works fine but when i view it using my phone. the design is different. it looks like it was zoomout and the position of the icon different. using a margin.

http://lycein.netne.net/OnlineClassManagementMobile/professor/pages/main.php

Comment: can send a screenshot from your mobile ?

Comment: Which icon are you talking about? The home icon or the settings/gear icon?

Comment: the gear one. why is it like that? i test it in a responsive web application. but in a actual phone its not what it seems to be

Comment: You say the site "looks fine" on a desktop computer, but 1) it displays nothing but a PHP error, 2) in the mobile view the text is an unreadable black on dark blue, and 3) when the user makes the window narrower, the gear icon gets larger, until on a _very_ narrow screen it gets smaller again. That can't all be by design, can it. Also, you see to be using `mysql_...` functions, which are deprecated in favour of `mysqli_...`